# using a button and a flag in javascript to change camera position in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

hello i am making a program to change a a camara position , by using keyboard and a flag that changes the orientation of the camera each time the keyword is pressed ,

```
var texturechao =  new THREE.TextureLoader().load("Objetos/floor_gold.jpg");
var cena = new THREE.Scene();

var spotLight_1= new THREE.SpotLight(0xbdc7de) 

//var camara = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
//var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
//----------parte diogo----------------------

var cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,innerWidth/innerHeight, 0.1,1000);
var renderer_a = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
cena.background = new THREE.Color(0xfafafa);
renderer_a.setSize(innerWidth,innerHeight);


//cameras
function init_Camera(){
cam.position.z= 5;
cam.position.y= 0;
}
function init_Spot(){
    spotLight_1.color.setHex(0xbdc7de);
    spotLight_1.position.set(0,5,0);
    spotLight_1.angle = Math.PI / 6;
    spotLight_1.penumbra = 0.05;
    spotLight_1.decay = 2;
    spotLight_1.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    spotLight_1.shadow.mapSize.Height = 1024;
    spotLight_1.shadow.camera.near = 10;
    spotLight_1.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
    
}

function flag_ini(){
    var cam_actio = 6;
    var spot = 4;
    var spaw = 4;

}

document.body.appendChild(renderer_a.domElement);
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight({color:0xFFFFFF, intensity: 100});
directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
var ambientLight =new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,0.5);
cena.add(ambientLight);
cena.add(spotLight_1);
spotLight_1.target.position.set(0,0,0);

let grid = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 20, 0x0a0a0a,0x0a0a0a);
grid.position.set(0, -0.5, 0);
cena.add(grid);
// controlo da camara
//let controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(cam,renderer_a.domElement);
let clock = new THREE.Clock();
// este é a imagem teste depois ignora
let bGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1); 
let bMat1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ({map:texturewalls});
let bMat2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ({map:texturewalls});
let bMat3 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ({map:texturewalls});
let bMat4 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ({map:texturewalls});
//let cube = new THREE.Mesh(bGeo,bMat1);
//cena.add(cube);

let cGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,1,20);
let tMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:0xff0100, wireframe:false});
let cMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({map:texturechao});
let chao = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo,cMat);
let teto = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo,tMat);
chao.position.set(0,-2.5,0);
teto.position.set(0,5.5,0);

cena.add(chao);
cena.add(teto);
let parede_x = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,10,2);
let parede_y = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,10,20);
let parede_1 = new THREE.Mesh(parede_x,bMat1);
let parede_2 = new THREE.Mesh(parede_y,bMat2);
let parede_3= new THREE.Mesh(parede_x,bMat3);
let parede_4 = new THREE.Mesh(parede_y,bMat4);
parede_1.position.set(0,3,10);
parede_2.position.set(10,3,0);
parede_3.position.set(0,3,-10);
parede_4.position.set(-10,3,0);

cena.add(parede_1);
cena.add(parede_2);
cena.add(parede_3);
cena.add(parede_4);
let keyboard = [];

addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{
    keyboard[e.key]= true;
});
addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
    keyboard[e.key]= false;
});


function process_keyboard(){
        



        
        if(  keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 0)){
            cam.position.set(0,3,9);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 1)){
            cam.position.set(0,3,-9);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 2)){
            cam.position.set(9,3,0);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;    
           
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 3)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(-9,3,0);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
        }        
    
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 4)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,3,0);
         
    }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 5)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(0,5,0);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
           
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 6 )){
            cam.position.set(0,0,5);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,5);
            cam_actio = 0;
          
        }
    
    

    if(keyboard['a']){
        spotLight_1.color.setHex(0xfe41ad);
        }
    if(keyboard['s']){
        spotLight_1.position.set(6,3,3);
        spotLight_1.target.position.set(3,0,0);
    }
    
    if(keyboard["d"]){
       spotLight_1.visible=false;
    }
    
    if(keyboard["f"]){
        cam.position.set(-9,3,0);
        cam.lookAt(20,0,0);
        spotLight_1.position.set(-9,3,0);
        spotLight_1.target.position.set(20,0,0);
        spotLight_1.color.setHex(0x9417b0);
    } 
    //position  
    if(keyboard["g"]){
        cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,3,0);
    }   

    if(keyboard["h"]){
        cam.position.set(0,5,0);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    }   
    //original
   
    if(keyboard["u"]){
        spotLight_1.visible=true;
        cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,5);
    } 
}


function drawScene(){
    flag_ini();
    init_Camera();
    init_Spot();
    process_keyboard();
    renderer_a.render(cena,cam);
 
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}
drawScene();
```

beyonde that the i don´t know if afther i click in q if the flag changes in one go or if the idividual partes are activate befre thath each if was associalted only to a keyword

```
        



        
        if(  keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 0)){
            cam.position.set(0,3,9);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 1)){
            cam.position.set(0,3,-9);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 2)){
            cam.position.set(9,3,0);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
            cam_actio += cam_actio;    
           
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 3)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(-9,3,0);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
        }        
    
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 4)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,3,0);
         
    }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 5)){
            cam_actio += cam_actio;
            cam.position.set(0,5,0);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
           
        }
        if( keyboard['q'] &&(cam_actio == 6 )){
            cam.position.set(0,0,5);
            cam.lookAt(0,0,5);
            cam_actio = 0;
          
        }
    
    

    if(keyboard['a']){
        spotLight_1.color.setHex(0xfe41ad);
        }
    if(keyboard['s']){
        spotLight_1.position.set(6,3,3);
        spotLight_1.target.position.set(3,0,0);
    }
    
    if(keyboard["d"]){
       spotLight_1.visible=false;
    }
    
    if(keyboard["f"]){
        cam.position.set(-9,3,0);
        cam.lookAt(20,0,0);
        spotLight_1.position.set(-9,3,0);
        spotLight_1.target.position.set(20,0,0);
        spotLight_1.color.setHex(0x9417b0);
    } 
    //position  
    if(keyboard["g"]){
        cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,3,0);
    }   

    if(keyboard["h"]){
        cam.position.set(0,5,0);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    }   
    //original
   
    if(keyboard["u"]){
        spotLight_1.visible=true;
        cam.position.set(0,0,5);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,5);
    } 
}
```

this functions is called in the draw functions

```
function drawScene(){
    flag_ini();
    init_Camera();
    init_Spot();
    process_keyboard();
    renderer_a.render(cena,cam);
 
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why not call the process_keyboard directly from the event listener instead of calling it in your draw loop